# Parse List<Document> to Lists in java

Tags: java, list, document

I have a **Document** as:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"
        },
        {
            "key1" : "value3",
            "key2" : "value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the best way to parse **Document** above to 2 List of String:

```
List<String> data.key1;
List<String> data.key2;
```

*Note: I use java8, org.bson.Document

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to cover all case to parse! But this solution does not work well.

Comment: What solution? You haven't shown anything

Comment: Of each level of key in Document, I check type of Object value, of each type I write a function to parse value.

Comment: can u use Jsonpath or any restriction on using this API.?

Comment: The [bson.org implementations page](http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html) shows 5 java implementations have your tried any of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `class` to hold a single object in list `data`:

```
class Data {
 private String key1;
 private String key2;
}
```

Parse JSON to your object with Jackson Mapper and get the list of fields:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Data> data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, List.class);

List<String> key1s = data.stream().map(d -> d.getKey1()).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> key2s = data.stream().map(d -> d.getKey2()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**: If you have [jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), then you can query more easily:

```
List<String> key1s = JsonPath.read("$.data[*].key1", jsonString);
List<String> key2s = JsonPath.read("$.data[*].key2", jsonString);
```

Comment: `O(2N)` seems like it could be more efficient

Comment: Thanks you so much! It is the best solution!

Comment: @ToànNguyễn  would you mind accepting the answer plz